# Sorting within group using yii2 gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2

Sample data:

```
╔═════╦══════════╦════╦════╦
║ Fo  ║ Bar      ║  Bar 2  ║
╠═════╬══════════╬═════════╬
║  6  ║     10   ║         ║
║  4  ║     110  ║         ║
║  3  ║     120  ║         ║
║  8  ║     140  ║         ║
║  3  ║     180  ║         ║
║  3  ║     190  ║         ║
╚═════╩══════════╩════╩════╩
```

Output:

```
╔═════╦══════════╦════╦════╦
║ Fo  ║ Bar      ║  Bar 2  ║
╠═════╬══════════╬═════════╬
║  3  ║     190  ║         ║
║  3  ║     180  ║         ║
║  3  ║     120  ║         ║
║  8  ║     140  ║         ║
║  4  ║     110  ║         ║
║  6  ║     10   ║         ║
╚═════╩══════════╩════╩════╩
```

I can sort it using PostgreSql

```
GROUP BY  "foo", "bar2" ORDER BY max("bar") OVER (PARTITION BY "foo") DESC
```

But I have customizable report with many different columns and groups. It would be nice to have a more flexible solution.

There may be a ready-made solution for Yii2?

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: There are many plugins for gridview, for customizing table with various options. Such as sub groups, groupRow, summary. But I can't find something to sort withing group.

Answer (score -1):

In  *ModelSearch.php*  file  add sorting before loading parameters to the model. For example;

```
   $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
   'query' => $query,
   'sort' => ['defaultOrder' => ['COLUMNNAME' => SORT_DESC]]
   ]);

    $this->load($params);
```

Comment: This sorting breaks grouping.
If I do ['Bar' => SORT_DESC] then 'fo' column will be 3-3-8-3-4-6
As you can see it's not grouped anymore.